# Is it possible to hide notifications for a specific App?

Tags: notifications

I can see a lot of Elementary Apps in the notification settings, and I know that I can hide the notifications for those apps. But what about the other apps grouped in the category "Other"? Can I hide the notifications for 1 specific app without hiding the rest of "Other" apps?

I specifically want to hide Spotify notifications, but if there is a generic solution this could help a lot of people.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

elementary relies on applications notifying the OS that they want to use notifications by setting a property in their `.desktop` file. Applications not built/controlled by elementary are not guaranteed to do this

You can add the following line to the bottom of the `.desktop` file for the application in question and it should show up in the notifications settings so you can configure it like the elementary applications.

```
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
```

For example, my `/usr/share/applications/spotify.desktop` file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Spotify
GenericName=Music Player
Comment=Spotify streaming music client
Icon=spotify-client
Exec=spotify %U
TryExec=spotify
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Audio;Music;Player;AudioVideo;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/spotify;
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
```

And my notification settings now have the Spotify application as a configurable notifications source:
[image]

This is not guaranteed to be a permanent fix, as the application in question may overwrite its `.desktop` file during updates, etc...

Comment: Has there been any changes to this? I can add this, and it does show in the notification settings, however, switching stuff off doesn't change anything.

Comment: I usually copy the desktop files into my `/home/arti/.local/share/applications` folder so I don't need to mess with sudo and changes are persistent in spite of updates.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it does not work for snap apps (?)

Comment: Who downvoted this like a moron? This solution indeed doesn't work for snap spotify. I had to remove `spotify.desktop` and delete disabled everything in `All Settings->Notification->Other`